# Transmission of serial data characters

Tags: digital-logic, uart, transmitter, baudrate

On a serial data link characters are transmitted data rate of 9600 baud. if characters are 8 bits and there is one start bit and one stop bit per character, then what is the number of characters transmitted per second.

Can someone explain to me how to get the answer.The given question is a multiple choice question (MCQ), so a short answer would work.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have 8 + 1 + 1 = 10 bits per character.
With 9600 baud, meaning bits/s, this means you can send 9600 bits/s / 10 bits/character = 960 characters/s.

Note, if a parity bit is used, 11 bits per character should be used for the calculation above.

Comment: Thanks a lot!This was very helpful!

Comment: Please upvote if the answer is helpful (and accept if it solves your problem).

Comment: Sorry, about that. But my reputation is less than 15

Comment: No problem .. thanks for the accept

Comment: For future reference: Here on EE.SE, we don't provide direct answers to homework/exam questions, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when the OP has demonstrated sufficient effort on their own. Otherwise, we would be doing them a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: @DaveTweed ok understood (that's why I gave not only the short answer but also an explanation, hope he learns from it). Besides, I learnt too (checking for the parity bit).